# Call cmdlet directly without loading it via $profile

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I created a cmdlet `*.ps1` file with a single `function Backup-Data` that I load into my `$profile` with `Import-Module Backup-Data.ps1`.

Everytime I test it, I save the file and reopen the powershell console but this process is very tedious. So, I was wondering whether there is a way to call that directly from the console?

Comment: You can use the same commands in the console you use in your profile. You might add the paramter `-Force` to make sure you overwrite your existing function definitions.

Comment: For a simple test cycle, paste the function into console and edit it in history, then <enter> to load it and call it, finally when development finishes, copy it into your cmdlet file.

Comment: @subcoder oh, this looks like a lot of work ;-] I think I'll stick with the remove/import procedure for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're defining new types in the `Backup-Data.ps1` script, the following should suffice for restarting your testing in an interactive session:

```
Remove-Module Backup-Data -Force
Import-Module Backup-Data.ps1
```